# Partial differential equations: intermediate manipulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to integrate a system of partial differential equations and I'm stuck at a certain point maybe just because I'm missing adequate basic knowledge on this topic. In the following expression in which $k$ and $b$ are simple constants and $A$ and $B$ are functions depending from $y$ and another variable $z$ only:

, where $m$ is another constant since in this way all the terms with a $x$ dependence are on the same side of the equal sign? Or what other manipulation should be carried out in this case to get an expression for $B(y,z)$?

Comment: If $A, B$ do not depend on $x$, then $x$ is a constant for the equation, not a variable. Just like $k$ and $b$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Does this mean that my identity is correct? How would you simplify this expression to get an expression for B(y,z)? I'm sorry I'm pretty lost with these manipulations

Comment: No, it does not mean your identity is correct. There is no reason that $m$ would be constant. What is means is that $A$ and $B$ have to depend on $x$, not just $y$ and $z$. In fact, since you are only differentiating with respect to $y$, this isn't a PDE. It is an ODE. However, with two different functions, it just establishes a relationship between the two functions - you can solve for one in terms of the other, but you cannot determine what both functions are just from it, You need a second equation to accomplish that.